# React-native passing props from App.js to other files

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to pass device token from my App.js to my Login component in react-native.

I'm trying something like this :

Here's my app.js :

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions :{ headerLeft: null}
    },
    Tab: {
      screen: Tab,
      navigationOptions :{ headerLeft: null }
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
  }
);

const MyApp = createAppContainer(RootStack);
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        token: ''
      }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.state.token = await firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token=> { return token;});
    this.checkPermission();
    this.createNotificationListeners();
  }

render() {
      return (
        <MyApp token={this.state.token}></MyApp>
      );
    }
```

And my Login.js :

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        mail:"",
        password: "",
        token: this.props.token
      }
  }

  async Login(){ 

console.log(this.state.token)

}

}
```

Of course it's not working, I don't know how to pass the token via components, or via stacknavigator without using .navigate(). Besides even if I fill the const with a single string, it's not working, so what am I doind wrong ?  And is it going to be different with the token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### screenProps

You need to use `screenProps`. You should check the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props) to see more about it.

This is how I would use it in your case.

```
<MyApp screenProps={{ token: this.state.token}} />
```

Then you can access it in your screens using `this.props.screenProps.token`.

Here is a snack that I created that shows passing values through a navigator. https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/passing-props-through-a-navigator

In your current `LoginScreen` you are trying to set the value of the token in the state. Bear in mind, your page may be constructed before the token is created so the initial value for the token may not exist so you may prefer to capture the value in `componentDidUpdate`, see the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for more.

Alternatively you could store the token in [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage).

#### Firebase

When getting your token from Firebase, you are mixing `promises` and `async/await` notation. Choose one notation and stick with it.

You are setting your state incorrectly. You are mutating state with your line

```
this.state.token = await firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token=> { return token;});
```

You should not mutate state as it can get overwritten, and it can cause side effects that you don't expect. You should use `this.setState({token});` to set your token value into state.

This is how I would refactor your `componentDidMount`

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // await functions can throw so always wrap them in a try/catch
  try {
    // get the token from firebase https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/device-token
    let token = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (token) {
     // if we have a token then set the state and use a callback
     // once the state has been the callback calls checkPermissions and createNotificationListeners
     this.setState({token}, () => {
       this.checkPermission();
       this.createNotificationListeners();
     });
   }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

#### Additional reading

The following articles by Michael Chan are a great introduction into state. 
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

The following article shows the differences between `promises` and `async/await`
https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! It is working now, but I have to reload twice for it to work though I get the token correctly in app.js, and componentDidUpdate create an infinite loop even though I wrapped my code in a condition like said on the doc ..

Comment: Update your question with the code from your componentDidUpdate, so I can see it